# Contractions semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $H$ Hilbert, $\{e_k\}$ orthonormal basis, $A \colon D(A) \subset H \to H$ generator of a strongly continuous semigroup $e^{At}$ and $A$ such that
$$Ae_k=-\lambda_k e_k$$
for some eigenvalues $\lambda_k>0$ such that $$\inf_k \lambda_k =\lambda>0$$

Then it follows by Hille-Yosida theorem that $$|e^{At}| \leq M e^{-\lambda t}$$
for some $M>0$.

Now my question is: is it true that $$|e^{At}| \leq e^{-\lambda t}$$
so that we can have $M=1$ and then say that $e^{At}$ is a semigroup of contractions?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is diagonalizable, the associated semigroup is given by
$$e^{A t} x =\sum_{k\ge 0} e^{-\lambda_k t} \langle x,e_k\rangle e_k, \qquad \forall t\ge 0, \forall x\in H.$$
Then by Pythagoras's Theorem,

\begin{align*}
|e^{At}x|^2 &=\sum_{k\ge 0} e^{-2\lambda_k t} |\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2\\
& \le e^{-2\lambda t} |x|^2, \qquad \forall x\in H.
\end{align*}